# Is there a GB size limit for SD card for a HTC evo phone?

Tags: google-contacts

So far can't find any info on GB size limit for the HTC evo phone. Is there one? HTC.com link is not working for the last few day.... so can't get tech support for the answer.

My problem, the phone comes with 2 GB SD card and work fine. Bought a 32 GB (10 speed I believe) and phone don't recognized that there is SD card installed and ask to insert one...

So, is there a GB size limit? forum info indicated that speed 6 would work but no info if 8 or 10 would work... any additional info is appreciated,

Comment: It should work regardless of the speed.  Most phones support up to 32 or 64 GB, [this says 32 GB for the EVO](http://www.htc.com/us/support/htc-evo-4g-lte-sprint/faq/6/).  Have you formatted the card?  What filesystem is it using?

Comment: Not every card works with every phone. Ask HTC which cards are known to work or try directly in the store.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to the HTC Evo 4G, the Supported limit (According to GSMArena) is 32GB.

GSMArena is usually pretty good for anything hardware related, so if the afore mentioned model is the one you have, try searching GSM for your model.

Source: [GSMArena](http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_evo_4g-3427.php)